# My pipeline build is successful but I needed to publish the results in .xml file which is happening locally but not in DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, pester

My pipeline build is successful but I needed to publish the results in .xml file which is happening locally but not in DevOps  - It says TestPester file not found.

When I use these commands locally - all tests are passed and it creates TestPester file automatically.

Command
`Invoke-Pester -Script Get-Planet.Tests.ps1 -OutputFile Test-Pester.XML -OutputFormat NUnitXML`

[image]

[image]

The pipeline code :

```
trigger:
 - main

pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest

steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    filePath: 'Get-Planet.Tests.ps1'
    workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
    script: |
      Install-Module -Name Pester -Force -SkipPublisherCheck

      Import-Module Pester

      Invoke-Pester -Script $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\Get-Planet.Tests.ps1 -OutputFile $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\TestPester.XML -OutputFormat NUnitXML     
      Invoke-Pester -CodeCoverage '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\Get-Planet.Tests.ps1' -CodeCoverageOutputFile '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\Pester-Coverage.xml' -CodeCoverageOutputFileFormat JaCoCo    


        
  
- task: PublishTestResults@2
  inputs:
      testResultsFormat: 'NUnit'
      testResultsFiles: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\TestPester.XML'
      mergeTestResults: true


- task: PublishCodeCoverageResults@1
  inputs:
    codeCoverageTool: 'JaCoCo'
    summaryFileLocation: '**/Pester-Coverage.xml'
    pathToSources: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
```

LOG FILE

```
2021-04-07T09:15:46.0910514Z ##[section]Starting: PublishTestResults
2021-04-07T09:15:46.1265107Z ==============================================================================
2021-04-07T09:15:46.1265611Z Task         : Publish Test Results
2021-04-07T09:15:46.1265893Z Description  : Publish test results to Azure Pipelines
2021-04-07T09:15:46.1266118Z Version      : 2.180.0
2021-04-07T09:15:46.1266332Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2021-04-07T09:15:46.1266847Z Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/publish-test-results
2021-04-07T09:15:46.1267241Z ==============================================================================
2021-04-07T09:15:47.1966443Z [command]"C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" --version
2021-04-07T09:15:48.7472296Z 5.0.201
2021-04-07T09:15:48.7517977Z ##[warning]No test result files matching D:\a\1\s\TestPester.XML were found.
2021-04-07T09:15:48.8193796Z ##[section]Finishing: PublishTestResults
```

Powershell logs :

Generating script.
Formatted command: . 'D:\a\1\s\Get-Planet.Tests.ps1'
========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoLogo -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command ". 'D:\a_temp\3dee7bed-1e4b-4a16-8e09-674f5ac01d78.ps1'"

Starting discovery in 1 files.
Discovery finished in 1.06s.
[+] D:\a\1\s\Get-Planet.Tests.ps1 5.22s (1.21s|3.05s)
Tests completed in 5.36s
Tests Passed: 6, Failed: 0, Skipped: 0 NotRun: 0
Finishing: PowerShell

Comment: Can you please check the option 'Enable system diagnostics', and then check the full logs about your powershell task? Please make sure your powershell task has created the 'TestPester.XML' file successfully and check where the file is.

Comment: @ShubhiSharma no the publish test task, the powershell task.

Comment: @YujunDing-MSFT - I think it's not creating the file itself

Comment: @YujunDing-MSFT - pasted detailed logs of powershell do check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added Get-Planet.Tests.ps1 my test file instead of PowerShell file. That is why I was getting error.

I changed it to :

```
- task: PowerShell@2
    inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      Install-Module -Name Pester -Force
  
  
      Invoke-Pester -CodeCoverage $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\Get-Planet.psm1 `
                -CodeCoverageOutputFile $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\Pester-Coverage.xml `
                -CodeCoverageOutputFileFormat JaCoCo `
                -OutputFile $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\test-results.xml `
                -OutputFormat NUnitXml
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following..

1. Add '' around your path to the first pester command output, sounds odd but worth a try
2. Add a test-path command using the path '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\TestPester.XML' before your publish task to make sure the file is being created

I find most of the time that the file has not been created or it can't properly resolve the path.

Comment: tried step 2 but doesn't show if file is created or not

Comment: If the test-path comes back with "true" then the file is there, if it's "false" the file is not there.  I have a feeling it wont be there, if so add a get-childitem  '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)' to see what files you actually have in that directory.  I did have problems ages ago with pre v5 pester ignoring any custom name you put for the output file